# Testing clustering algorithms for accuracy in weka Experimenter

Tags: java, weka

I'm using Experimenter to compare clustering algorithms to test accuracy. I couldn't find clustering algorithms in the Simple experiment mode, so I used Advanced and did the clustering using these steps:

https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/experimenter/running_an_experiment_using_clusterers/

These are my settings:

[image: Experimenter settings]

And this is my analysis screen.

[image: Analysis]

I can't find 'Percent_correct' here though to test accuracy. How can I test for accuracy?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Accuracy (ie Percent_correct) is only available from supervised algorithms like classifiers and cluster algorithms are unsupervised.

Comment: I see, thanks! Is there a way to compare the % of incorrectly clustered instances though, like in Explorer?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. You'd have to write custom code for obtaining the classes-to-clusters information and post-process that further.